# Help getting Mercurial running on a Media Temple (gs)

Tags: mercurial, mediatemple

I've installed Mercurial per MT's knowledge base file [here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1639/Installing+Mercurial+on+the+%2528gs%2529+Grid-Service).

Working with it server side using ssh from my Mac works fine. I can initialize repositories and the like, but pulling from the server or pushing from my Mac produces an error I don't understand.

Here's what I get when call hg push from my local installation (hash marks represent my server number):

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/home/#####/users/.home/data/mercurial-1.5/hg", line 27, in ?
remote:     mercurial.dispatch.run()
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
remote:     sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 21, in dispatch
remote:     u = _ui.ui()
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/ui.py", line 38, in __init__
remote:     for f in util.rcpath():
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/util.py", line 1200, in rcpath
remote:     _rcpath = os_rcpath()
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/util.py", line 1174, in os_rcpath
remote:     path = system_rcpath()
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/posix.py", line 41, in system_rcpath
remote:     path.extend(rcfiles(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) +
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/posix.py", line 30, in rcfiles
remote:     rcs.extend([os.path.join(rcdir, f)
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 75, in __getattribute__
remote:     self._load()
remote:   File "/nfs/c05/h01/mnt/#####/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _load
remote:     mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
remote: ImportError: No module named osutil
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Mercurial on my Mac is configured as follows

```
[ui]
username = John Smith
editor = te -w
remotecmd = ~/data/mercurial-1.5/hg
```

My local single repo is configured as follows (hash marks represent my server number):

```
[paths]
default = ssh://mysite.com@s#####.gridserver.com/domains/mysite.com/html
```

Mercurial on the server is configured with a just a username:

```
[ui]
username = John Smith
```

The server .bash_profile is configured as follows (per the installation guide):

```
# Added this as suggested by the MediaTemple guide
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

I understand this probably isn't a MediaTemple problem, but more likely an installation problem. I would really appreciate any assitance on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mercurial installation isn't complete, you didn't compile the osutil module (there should be a osutil.so somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm looking for any documentation that could point me where to fix that problem, but I just can't seem to find it. Any ideas? I'm really not that great at debugging this type of stuff.

Comment: @bschaeffer `hg debuginstall` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

@tonfa,

`hgdebuginstall` produced no errors, which is why the problem I was having was so weird.

Thanks to your response, I did some digging and found the module in `~/lib/python/mercurial`, so I copied the `osutil.so` file over to my `~data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial` directory and that was that... but then more and more modules couldn’t be found so I decided to copy the entire contents of one directory over to the other, like so:

```
$ rm -R ~/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial/*
$ cp -r ~/lib/python/mercurial/* ~/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial
```

Now, everything works fine. I don't understand why it seems that mercurial was installed in two directories, or why one directory (`~/data/mercurial-1.5/mercurial`) didn't get the same files as the other (`~/lib/python/mercurial`).

Anyway, this is the solution I came up with. If you (or anyone) can think of something more elegant, I'd be all ears, but as it is... this one works for me.

Thanks for your time.